# Javascript construct in concatenating strings

Tags: javascript, string

Below a simple piece of javascript is displayed:

```
var mystring = ("random","ignored","text","h") + ("ello world")
```

This string results in hello world. I have two questions:

- how is the ("random","ignored","text","h") construct called (its not
  an array, because an array has different kind of brackets?)
- Can someone technically explain why this string results in hello world? (i.e. why is only the "h" character in the construct taken into account?)

Comment: https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're running into the little-known [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)!

The parentheses and comma operator create a group of expressions that are evaluated in order, then return the last one. So `('foo', 'bar')` will evaluate to just `'bar'`. However, because each expression is evaluated, `(foo(), bar())` will call *both* `foo()` and `bar()` before returning the value returned by `bar()`.

Step by step, your code runs as:

```
var mystring = ("random","ignored","text","h") + ("ello world")
var mystring = "h" + ("ello world")
var mystring = "h" + "ello world"
var mystring = "hello world"
```

Many (or even most) languages have this operator, but it's rarely used. It can be helpful when using ES6 lambdas as the body of a `reduce`, like when you're turning an array into an object:

```
[{key: 'a', value: 1}, {key: 'b', value: 2}].reduce((p, c) => (p[c.key] = c.value, p), {})
```

I wouldn't necessarily suggest you use it often, since it can be confusing and there's often a more clear (if more verbose) way to do the same thing.

Comment: This is fastest to-the-point answer I have ever seen. Thanks! :)